# Django - Difference b/w Django-rpy2 & rpy2

Tags: django, rpy2

Django is showing two rpy2 related packages

```
 Django-rpy2
 rpy2
```

Are they both different like i am familiar with rpy2 but what does Django-rpy2 offer? I am unable to find something in django-rpy2 documentation. What is it all about?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `django-rpy2` offers some features related to Django models but almost no documentation and the last package update is from July 2015, I don't recommend using it. Just use Django and Rpy2 separately (if you really have to use Rpy2). Check the [source](http://pydoc.net/django-rpy2/0.7.1/django_rpy2/) for more details ([especially the models](http://pydoc.net/django-rpy2/0.7.1/django_rpy2.models/)).

Comment: Yes It seems not working at all & i wanted to confirm. Thanks for the response !